# Different ways to trim the mean with different results

Tags: r, mean, distribution

Suppose I want to calculate the trimmed mean of the following data:

```
set.seed(1)
s<-rnorm(10,100,20)
#[1]  87.47092 103.67287  83.28743 131.90562 106.59016  83.59063 109.74858 114.76649 111.51563  93.89223
```

I can use the mean function with a trim parameter of, say, 0.05, which gives a trimmed mean of 102.6441.

```
mean(s, trim = 0.05)
# 102.6441
```

However, if I decide to trim the mean by manually using only data that lies between the 0.05 quantile and the 0.95 quantile, I get a trimmed mean of 101.4059

```
mean(s[which(s <= quantile(s, 0.95) & s >= quantile(s, 0.05))])
# 101.4059
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour? What does the trim parameter in the mean function actually do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source to the function is available if you type `mean.default`.  What it does is to calculate `lo <- floor(n * trim) + 1` and `hi <- n + 1 - lo`, then calculate the mean of sorted values from `lo` to `hi`.  Your dataset is small so with `trim = 0.05`, you get the entire dataset and the trimmed mean is the same as the full mean.

On the other hand, the `quantile()` function uses a complicated definition of quantiles that interpolates between values.  So your method effectively uses `lo <- ceiling(n * trim) + 1`, since it will certainly drop the smallest and largest values for any positive value of `trim`.

Answer (score 1):

The `trim` argument according to the document of `?mean`:

> the fraction (0 to 0.5) of observations to be trimmed from each end of
> x before the mean is computed. Values of trim outside that range are
> taken as the nearest endpoint.

Using `trim` will delete a certain percentage of the dataset's smallest and greates values. So if you want to trim the data between the 0.05 and 0.95 quantile you should use `trim = 0.1` like this:

```
set.seed(1)
s<-rnorm(10,100,20)
mean(s, trim = 0.1)
```

Output:

```
[1] 101.4059
```

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted the documentation.  `trim = 0.05` says to trim 5% from each end.  The problem arises because `n = 10` is such a small dataset that it ends up trimming none.  Try a dataset of size 100, and you'll see that entries 6 through 95 of the sorted data are used when `trim = 0.05`.